# Iterate list by first element then first AND second element etc

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dataframes and each dataframe has a categorical attribute 'landType'.

```
df_list = [df1,df2,df3]

df1.landType.unique() == A,B
df2.landType.unique() == B
df3.landType.unique() == B,C
```

I want to create a new list that contains the number of unique values but takes into account the previous iterations i.e.:

```
len(df1.landType.unique()) == 2
len(df1 AND df2.landType.unique()) == 2
len(df1 AND df2 AND df3.landType.unique()) == 3

output_list = [2,2,3]
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would be helpful for you to include some code for what you've already tried, to make a complete [mcve] so we know how best to assist

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.accumulate`.

Comment: I think I should have asked the question in a different way - I updated it with a more definitive example - thank you for your answers to the previous version though!

Comment: _categorical attribute 'landType'_ An attribute? Do you mean a column? Can you share what the DataFrames look like? See: [mcve]. What do you mean by _takes into account the previous iterations_ ? It looks to me like you're just merging the columns, and then counting the number of unique values, right?

Answer (score 0):

This very basic approach of having a new blank list b, traversing through all the items in list a, adding accumulated values to each element and keep on appending to b will give you the result (other than itertools methods)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [] 
acum = 0
for i in a:
    b.append(i+acum)
    acum += i
print (b)
[1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The new assignment expression in Python 3.8 can be used to keep a running total of all the `x`s seen so far.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = 0
>>> [(y := y + x) for x in a]
[1, 3, 6]
```

This application of the new syntax generalizes what `itertools.accumulate` already does.

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(a))
[1, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up like this:

```
out_put_list = [len(pd.concat(df_list[y][0:i+1]).reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)['landType'].unique())
                        for i in range(len(df_list[y]))]
```

pd is the pandas module